# Solving sparse least squares system with limited memory

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, least-squares

This was a question on a past final that we can't figure out: take the least squares system $\min_x ||Ax-b||_2$, where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{mxn}$, $m<n$, and A is full rank. A has $\mathcal{O}(n)$ non-zero entries. Assume you only have $\mathcal{O}(n)$ computer memory.

1. Suggest an algorithm for approximating the solution to the least squares problem
2. What is the expected number of iterations and overall computational cost?
3. What is the expected error in the solution x? (Provide an appropriate definition of error for this problem)

We've only learned a little bit about iterative methods, just like Rayleigh Quotient, Inverse Iteration, Power Iteration, and Conjugate Gradient. None of these seem to help. Any ideas would be much appreciated, thank you!

**Edit**: I'm thinking now, what if we take a random $m$ columns so that a square matrix can be formed, and then use CG on that problem? And then do this with various random columns to find average solutions?

Comment: You speak of "the least squares solution", but since your problem is underdetermined, there are going to be infinitely many least squares solutions.  Do you want the minimum norm least squares solution?